# AdMob findViewById returns null

Tags: android

I'm trying to configure AdMod in my first Android project. When I try to run the app, findViewByID always returns null.

Here's the code of my main activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.Window;


   import android.view.WindowManager;

public abstract class MyAndroidApp extends Activity {
    AdView adView;
    public static final  String MY_PUBLISHER_ID = "***********";

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_PUBLISHER_ID);

    //R.id.main has value, I can see it in Eclipse
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);


    if ( mainLayout == null )
        Log.d("Error","Layout is null");
    else
    mainLayout.addView(adView);

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The XML File (under res\layout) has the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyApp"     
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I debug, I can see value for R.id.main. However, the value of mainLayout is still null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order for findViewById to work you must have previously called setContentView

Answer (score 7):

Problem is that you are not calling `setContentView()` in onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.layoutId);
   RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
}
```

Without it you will get always **`NPE`** because UI elements don't have created instances(purpose of setContentView method) and View returned by `findViewById()` is assigned to **`NULL`**.

So add this one line and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The `setContentView` method should be called with appropriate layout before calling `findViewById`. It is usually called in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` method.